# How many albums are intentionally designed to synchronize with films?

Tags: album, film

Some albums have been found to coincidentally synchronize with famous films. The most noteworthy example of this is Pink Floyd’s *Dark Side of the Moon* purportedly synchronizing with *The Wizard of Oz*. However, this appears to be a complete coincidence rather than an intentional choice by the artists.

The only example of an album that was intentionally designed to synchronize with a film is Turkuaz’s *Digitonium*, [which perfectly synchronizes with Disney’s *The Sword in the Stone*](https://liveforlivemusic.com/news/turkuazs-new-album-synchronizes-with-the-sword-and-the-stone-watch/). (It’s definitely not a coincidence; some of the film’s dialog appears in the background of interlude tracks, and some sound effects from the film appear as well.)

Aside from this, are there any examples of albums that a band deliberately recorded so as to synchronize with a famous film? (I’m excluding soundtracks, as those are of course crafted alongside the films in question.)